# How to upload pictures to jCrop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, upload, jcrop

I've used the codes I've found from here: http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php?demo=thumbnail, but there isn't an upload function. How do I add that?

Like if I use this function how can I implement jCrop?

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="save.php" method="POST"> 
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" /> 
Choose a file to upload:  <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br /> 
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" /> </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't upload images to jCrop, you apply jCrop to your image element.

`$(function(){ $('#id_of_your_image_element').Jcrop(); });`

replace `id_of_your_image_element` with the id of your image tag, if you don't have an id on that tag, add one.

Comment: Aaaah... Makes sense.So if I wanted a user to be able to upload a picture and then apply jCrop to it how would I do that?

Comment: @Funkypotato You would have to split this into a multi step process, provide user an upload form, save the image on your server, host that image back to them in a new page, apply jCrop to that image, post those coordinates to another page and use the server application language to handle the actual cropping. The details are going to vary based on your server language. In the end all jCrop is going to do for you is give you an x,y coordinate of the upper left hand point of the crop area relative to the image, and the height and width of the crop area.